# Set default policy in Finder "View Options"

Tags: macos, finder

I have set icon size, grid spacing, and ordering policy in Finder's "View Options" according to my personal preferences. Then I have pushed the "set as default" button and according to my understanding this should provide the Finder with default settings for displaying folder content.

Unfortunately, this approach does not work in any case. Some Folders open according to different settings and I wonder why this is the case. Could it be that the default settings are ignored in certain cases? Maybe it does make a difference if the settings for particular folders have been manually changed before? How can I enforce default settings once and for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just hold the Option key and the "Set as Defaults" button will become "Restore to Defaults".
There no way to restore all folders to default.

Comment: This answer is a bit cryptic but here's what I derive from it:

if I encounter a folder that deviates from my default settings and then open the "View Options" dialog, option-click on the "set as default button" that by pressing option becomes "restore to default" the icon size and grid spacing is adjusted according to my personal preferences.

This is not *exactly* what I wanted to achieve but it is better than nothing, after all.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for disk images (at least, not in [certain cases](https://superuser.com/q/705675/144700)).