# How to open all files in list view in Finder of mac

Tags: macos

How to open all files in list view in Finder of mac?
I have try "use as default" in the views>show view options for a particular folder but it does not work.

Comment: It doesn't work quite how you think... 'default' is only default for that view-type - see https://superuser.com/questions/93641/setting-a-single-folders-view-options-vs-setting-the-default-view-options-for?noredirect=1&lq=1 for some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this, but will involve using *Terminal* to complete the following steps:

#### 1. Backup *com.apple.finder.plist*

`cp ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist ~/Desktop`

#### 2. Set default folder view using the `defaults` command

Default to *list view*:

defaults write com.apple.finder FXPreferredViewStyle Nlsv

#### 3. Clear the *.DS_Store* files

```
sudo rm /.DS_Store
find ~ -name .DS_Store -type f -delete
```

This may take a few minutes to complete.

#### 4. Restart *cfprefsd* and *Finder*

```
killall cfprefsd Finder
```

All your folders shoulder open up in *list view* from here on.  If anything goes wrong with the settings, or you decide you want/need to revert, simply:

```
cp ~/Desktop/com.apple.finder.plist ~/Library/Preferences/
```

and repeat step 4.  However, your former settings for individual folders won't be recovered, as these are stored per-folder in the *.DS_Store* files, which would need to have been deleted in order to allow the list-view default to take effect.

**Note:**  This was tested on MacOS 10.13, but will work in fairly recent, older versions of MacOS too.