# How do I make Finder use my default view options for disk images?

Tags: macos, finder

I've set the default view options (using the `Use as Defaults` button in the View Options panel). This is what I expect, and, indeed, what I get *most* of the time:
[image: preferred view options]

Yet every time I create a disk image (with Disk Utility, or `hdiutil create`), Finder seems to use some alternate set of defaults, resulting in this:
[image: default view options for disk images]
Existing images also revert to this style occasionally. I haven't noticed any pattern in when it happens. It never affects folders on the image, either, only the root of the image itself.

The only differences (besides that the toolbar and sidebar are hidden) seem to be in the icon size and grid spacing. Additionally, once I change the view options back to my preferences, the `Use as Defaults` button dims, indicating that the defaults haven't been changed—they just haven't been applied to the image for some reason. Holding down the option key with the View Options panel open changes the button to `Restore to Defaults`, but clicking it doesn't apply the default options.

Why doesn't the Finder apply my default view options to disk images, and how do I get it to?